# Docsplit on Heroku

Tags: heroku

Has anyone successfully used docsplit on Heroku? It has many binary dependencies. I've searched but haven't found anyone doing this. A tutorial would be great, but really I'm just curious if others have been successful.

Answer (score 0):

My searches don't turn up anyone who has done this. It looks like you'd have to create a [buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) and pull in the Docsplit dependencies [as outline here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-binaries).

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference, you could do this by using the "multi" buildpack and the "vendorbinaries" buildpack.

https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

https://github.com/peterkeen/heroku-buildpack-vendorbinaries

The idea being that you could specify the "multi" buildpack in your BUILDPACK_URL env variable and then in your .buildpacks file, specify the "ruby" and "vendorbinaries" buildpacks.  Then in the .vendor_urls file, specify the urls to the source code for each dependency of Docsplit.

You probably want to download the specific version of the source you want and host it on S3 so you always get the correct version for your needs.